# iOS build with expiry date

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, google-fabric, app-distribution

I have to distribute a iOS build with a validity period such as validity for 3 week or 1 month. Before that I have to revoke the access of that build. Is possible to do this in fabric? Or there is any other methods to do this other than Testflight?

Answer (score 3):

Though its not clear by the question I am considering that you want to do this programatically by the virtue of the tags used in your question.

You can write code which would check the date/number of app launches till date and would show an alert message with no buttons to close it which will block the access of the user from the app. This may be frustrating but would be effective.

If you want to do this from app store then you can remove the app from sale, check more of it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW17).

Also there are some other options like [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) which creates a installable link for a specific duration with free and paid versions available.